# How to make API work in background using Ionic 1

Tags: ionic-framework

I have developed an app for which i want to call some 2-3 API continuously in background mode though the app is killed using Ionic 1.

Is there any procedure to do so, as i have already wasted  much time in the search for that but no use. If any, please help me with example

Comment: what have you done so far? show the code

Comment: @lakshay, I have tried to work out with service-worker.js, cordova plugin with background, but not able to implement fruitfully. If you have done any, please let me know

Comment: what do you want to do.....do you want to make some api's calls when app is initialized.

Comment: @lakshay, I want to call API continuously in the background mode. for sending the data or locations... even though the app is killed.

Comment: https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode

Comment: @lakshay, Already I am trying that, but not able to implement that. That what i said any example or procedure to do. Further we can chat on hangouts. My id is nitinak511@gmail.com

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158595/discussion-between-lakshay-and-nitin-agarwal).